# When to Add Shards to a Distributed Key/Value Store

Tags: concurrency, storage, distributed-computing, key-value-store

I've been reading up on distributed systems lately, and I've seen a lot of examples of how to shard key value stores, like a memcache system or a nosql db.

In general, adding shards makes intuitive sense to me when you want to support more concurrent access to the table, and most of the examples cover that sort of usage.  One thing I'm not clear on though is whether you are *also* supposed to add shards as your total table size grows.  For something like a memcache, I'd imagine this is necessary, because you need more nodes with more memory to hold more key/values.  But what about databases which also keep the values on some sort of hard drive?

It seems like, if your table size is growing but the amount of concurrent access is not, it would be somewhat wasteful to keep adding nodes just to hold more data.  In that case I'd think you could just add more long-term storage.  But I suppose the problem is, you are increasing the chance that your data becomes "cold" when somebody needs it, causing more latency for those requests.

Is there a standard approach to scaling nodes vs. storage?  Are they always linked?  Thanks much for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the other way around.

Almost always shards are added because the data is growing to the point where it cannot be held on 1 machine

Sharding makes everything so much more painful so should be only done when vertical scaling doesn't work anymore